# How can I show files only in Total Commander?

Tags: file-management, total-commander, directory-listing

I don't want to use standard SEARCH (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> in Total Commander.

Instead, I would like the option to display all files (including those in subfolders of current directory).

Is there a way to do it in Total Commander or others?

I'm thinking of something like UltraSearch or Everything (programme), but it doesn't necessarily need to index the whole HDD, just a particular directory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> (or the corresponding menu item) to activate the "Branch View" mode.